# Awaiting state - One scenario with multiple When/Then versus Two scenarios and shared context

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

We are starting SpecFlow implementation and we are trying to find the best practice regarding a feature which required an awaiting state during the flow.

Should we use one scenario with several When/Then to test the Feature?
Or should we use two scenarios with a shared context?

Let's take the following fictive example: A contract creation following a product sale.
Steps from the contract management products view:

1. (When) An event is received with contract creation details
2. (Then) System A create a process for the new contract
3. (And) System A asks for the Client information to System B (Awaiting state occurs there)
4. (When) System A receives Client information
5. (Then) System A packages all contract-related information and publish them to other system

Implementation above is just to give you an idea of our problem.

Should we go with a big sceario like this:

- **When** An event is received with contract creation details
- **Then** System A create a process for the new contract
- **And** System A asks for the Client information to System B
- **When** System A receives Client information from System B
- **Then** System A packages all contract-related information and publish them to other system

Or with two distinct scenarios like this:

1 - Acknowledged contract creation

- **When** An event is received with contract creation details
- **Then** System A create a process for the new contract
- **And** System A asks for the Client information to System B

2 - Contract creation publication

- **When** System A receives Client information from System B
- **Then** System A packages all contract-related information and publish them to other system

We are not sure what is the best practice to follow in this particular case.

Find best practice for SpecFlow features required awaiting steps and multiple systems interractions

Comment: To be honest, the "best practice" is "focus on the business process, not the technical details." These scenarios describe the technical implementation of the system. I see lots of people write this style of test with Gherkin, and it's simply the wrong tool for the job, but I understand why people still use it.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Indeed, I tend to agree with you.
Business scenario would be something like this I guess: 
When A sale occurs
Then Contract informations are available to the advisor

But as you said, we evolve around the technical details and our product is purely backend (Kafka events pass through kind of).
Which tool would you recommend in this case?

Comment: This is where the philosophical overhead of Gherkin and BDD isn't necessarily beneficial anymore. The only other alternative is using plain old code. The question becomes, does Gherkin and SpecFlow bring enough advantages to make it useful? If it does, use it. This is also why I'm not necessarily a fan of "best practices." It's OK to use your own judgement about a tool.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the first two parts are setup, the second part the action, and the last part the effect. So:

```
    Given An event is received with contract creation details
    And System A create a process for the new contract
    When System A asks for the Client informations to System B
    Then System A receives Client informations from System B
    And System A packages all contract-related informations and publish them to other system
```

Or if everything is triggered by the first step, then it would be a single `When` followed by a `Then` and a few `And` after that.

```
    When An event is received with contract creation details
    Then System A create a process for the new contract
    And System A asks for the Client informations to System B
    And System A receives Client informations from System B
    And System A packages all contract-related informations and publish them to other system
```

You may at that point consider using the `*` keyword. If specflow supports it.